# How do I create and store a new object of a different type in to a specific Array list from the set methods?

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I am working on creating a GUI for a Gadget Shop that stores details of gadgets such as Mobile phones and MP3 players but I do not know how to return and store the values of these details as a new object of its type into the ArrayList of type Gadget.

I have done a lot of trial & error but could not be sure as to whether I was actually making any progress or not.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class GadgetShop implements ActionListener
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JTextField modelTextField;
    private JTextField priceTextField;
    private JTextField weightTextField;
    private JTextField sizeTextField;
    private JTextField initialCreditTextField;
    private JButton addMobileButton;
    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<Gadget> gadgets;

    /**
     * The GUI is created in the constructor.
     */
    public GadgetShop()
    {
        // initialise instance variables

        ArrayList<Gadget> gadgets = new ArrayList<Gadget>();

        frame = new JFrame("The Gadget Shop");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        modelTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(modelTextField);

        priceTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(priceTextField);

        weightTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(weightTextField);

        sizeTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(sizeTextField);

        initialCreditTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(initialCreditTextField);

        addMobileButton = new JButton("Add Mobile");
        contentPane.add(addMobileButton);
        addMobileButton.addActionListener(this);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * The main method allows the program to be run without BlueJ.
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GadgetShop calculator = new GadgetShop();
    }

    /**
     * Find which button triggered the event and call the appropriate method.
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Add Mobile")) {
            addMobile();
        }
    }
```

Below are the getMethods for the details of an object

```
    public String getModel()
    {
        String model
           = modelTextField.getText();
        return model;
    }

    public String getSize()
    {
        String size
           = sizeTextField.getText();
        return size;
    }

    public int getWeight()
    {
        int weight
           = Integer.parseInt(weightTextField.getText());
        return weight;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        double price
           = Double.parseDouble(priceTextField.getText());
        return price;
    }

    public int getCredit()
    {
        int credit
           = Integer.parseInt(initialCreditTextField.getText());
        return credit;
    }
```

Below is my setMethod for storing the object of type Mobile into the Gadget ArrayList which I believe is wrong

```
    public void addMobile()
    {
        String mobile =
           getModel();    //Is this how I call the get Methods??
           getPrice();
           getWeight();
           getSize();
           getCredit();
        gadgets = new Mobile();
        gadgets.add(mobile);   //I get an error with the .add part
    }

}
```

I expected errors because I was not sure whether I had created the ArrayList correctly in the first place.

Comment: `mobile`is a `String`instance, `gadgets`is a list of `Gadget`instance. That should highlight the issue.

Comment: Basically, you forgot to create a class named `Mobile` that extends `Gadget` and whose constructor accepts model, price etc.

Comment: I already have a class named Mobile. I just need to know what changes exactly I'd need to make to the set method or any other part of the code. Sorry but I am a complete newbie at this stuff.

Comment: If you already have class Mobile, try creating a new instance of this class in addMobile, and add that instance to gadgets ArrayList

Comment: I've added a new instance in the set method but still getting errors

Comment: Re-read @RealSkeptic 's comment or post your Mobile class implementation.

Comment: I believe I have fixed it, thanks.